# Cross is showing in RDLC report in place of image after export

Tags: c#, .net, report, rdlc

I have a RDLC report in which I have used Image tool to show image. This is working fine when I'm displaying this report in browser(showing blank in place of image if any row does not contain image) but when I export the report then the rows which don't have image is showing cross in place of image. It supposed to show blank instead of cross sign. Can anybody suggest me the possible solution?

Answer (score 2):

Showing blank is the browser support. If the path is invalid some browsers may show cross as it is shown on your report. If you need to show empty image box then you need to assign a default image, **a transparent image is a good option**.

Answer (score 0):

In [ReportExport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.reportexport%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Event  of report viewer you can customize your export. This may help you for replacing the row without image.